# CSS keep elements maximum top and left

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a website with PHP.

```html
<span style="height:60px;"></span>
<span style="height:90px;"></span>
<span style="height:95px;"></span>
<span style="height:45px;"></span>
<span style="height:60px;"></span>
<span style="height:70px;"></span>
<span style="height:55px;"></span>
<span style="height:60px;"></span>
<span style="height:40px;"></span>
```

The spans above are some posts.
And its CSS is:

```css
span{
    width:150px;
    margin:1px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

I got this result: http://jsfiddle.net/5kPFJ/3

But I need a result like this: http://jsfiddle.net/56ybX/
I used `<div>` with some CSS to keep these spans maximum top.
But I need this result without the `<div>` tag.
What should I do?

Comment: Look into using something like [**masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/). I use it all the time, its very good and does exactly this!

Comment: As @ruddy correctly states, this is not yet universally possible in pure CSS. You need some JS lib indeed, and masonry is a good popular one.

Comment: how about using flexbox? If you don't care about supporting ie8/ie9 i think this is possible

Comment: As @Ruddy said, you can use masonry library. It is not possible to do this without div at least.

Answer (score 1):

you should have some kind of wrapper to hold the column when you float some thing it's display become block so the spans are block now you can't do what you want . you should make 3 column float and inside them put your spans and the container can be any html element you can change the behave of that element with css

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/5kPFJ/10/

*Please note the use of an external reset.css file being included in the external resources as it's a big part of why this works*

**HTML**

```
<section class="flex-row">
    <article class="flex-col item1">
        <p class="item1">item1</p>
        <p class="item2">item2</p>
        <p class="item1">item1</p>
    </article>
    <article class="flex-col item1">
        <p class="item1">item1</p>
        <p class="item1">item1</p>
        <p class="item3">item3</p>
    </article>
    <article class="flex-col item1">
        <p class="item4">item4</p>
        <p class="item2">item2</p>
        <p class="item2">item2</p>
    </article>
    <article class="flex-col item1">
        <p class="item1">item1</p>
        <p class="item1">item1</p>
        <p class="item1">item1</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
section { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 1em; }
article { background: black; }
p { border: 1px solid white; padding: 1em; color: white; }

/* Flex Box */
.flex-col { display: flex; flex-flow: column; }
.flex-row { display: flex; flex-flow: row; }
.flex { display: flex; }
.item1 { flex: 1; }
.item2 { flex: 2; }
.item3 { flex: 3; }
.item4 { flex: 4; }
```

Comment: Sorry, But I am not looking like that you gave..
In a **div** I types some **span** s that in different height and same width. But the **span**s should go to top and left maximum they can..
I use float:left to keep it left. but how can I keep it to Top

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You will play with position absolute and some simple math.

```
span{
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    margin:1px;
}
span:nth-child(1){
    top:0;
    left:0;   
    background-color: red;
}

span:nth-child(2){
    top:65px;
    left:0px;   
    background-color: red;
}
span:nth-child(3){   
    top:160px;
    left:0px;   
    background-color: red;
}
span:nth-child(4){   
    top:0px;
    left:155px;   
    background-color: yellow;
}

span:nth-child(5){   
    top:50px;
    left:155px;   
    background-color: yellow;
}

span:nth-child(6){   
    top:115px;
    left:155px;   
    background-color: yellow;
}
span:nth-child(7){   
    top:0px;
    left:310px;   
    background-color: blue
}
span:nth-child(8){   
    top:60px;
    left:310px;   
    background-color: blue
}
span:nth-child(9){   
    top:125px;
    left:310px;   
    background-color: blue
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5kPFJ/3/